# JFrame renders graphics randomly

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I am new to Java game programming.  I have followed a few tutorials and watched a few videos.  I'm obviously doing something wrong because the graphics display one out of every 10 times I load the app.

The game concept is a soccer playbook.  My goal is to teach my 8 year old what part of the field to be in when different scenarios exist.

I am using Eclipse as the IDE.  Below is a summary of the classes and relevant members.  The classes represented below are used to draw a field and a few lines on the field.

Note: A lot of the logic has been removed to minimize the size of this post.  Please let me know if you need more information.

```
public class SoccerPlaybook {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SoccerPlaybook();
  }

  public SoccerPlaybook() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new Game(this));
  }
}

public class Game extends JPanel {

  public Game(SoccerPlaybook soccerPlaybook) {
    this.soccerPlaybook = soccerPlaybook;
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {      
    field.paintComponent(g);
  } 
}

public class Field extends JPanel {

  public Field(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, game.getSoccerPlaybook().getWidth(), game.getSoccerPlaybook().getHeight());

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawLine(200, 50, 400, 50);
    g.drawLine(200, 300, 400, 300);
    g.drawLine(200, 50, 200, 300);
    g.drawLine(325, 100, 400, 100);
    g.drawLine(325, 250, 400, 250);
    g.drawLine(325, 100, 325, 250);
  } 
}
```

I have tried using paint and paintComponent.  Both appear to have identical results.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This will layout the frame and ensure it gets displayed. You should do it just after you have added the Game JPanel.

You may also find that you need to set a preferred size for the Game JPanel. If so, put something like the following inside the Game constructor:

```
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimensions(600, 400));
```